# Content Editor Web part is not showing "Rich Text and Source Edit" options int he browser

Tags: sharepoint-designer

In my sharepoint 2010 desiner project I am not getting displayed of "Rich Text and Source Editor" options for Content Editor Webpart . The more surprising issue is if I run the project on my local server, the web part is displayed with all the options, but if I run the same project on the remote server, the fallowing options are missing. Can any one have any idea about this type of problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Baluk

Answer (score 0):

I have found an issue that if you start a `<style>` in the Content Editor Webpart and do not close the tag, it will not display the drop down for the  edit menu for the Web Part.  Have you added any styles to the Web Part?  The way I fixed this was having to delete the Web Part and add a new one.

Answer (score 0):

- Check the IE versions you are on. It works fine in IE6, problems are in IE8. You may have to enable compatability view.
- Try adding it in trusted site zone.

Cheers !
Rajdeep